# Anyone have an idea why this deployment is failing since I updated from aws-sdk v2 to v3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, deployment, rubygems

this is my first time posting here btw, sorry for any mistakes.
yea so the deployment exactly stopped working when I upgraded the aws-sdk gem from version 2 to version 3.
I tried to create a new app on heroku AND from the console, didnt work deploying.
I sometimes i got the error trying to upload the same branch eventho it was a newer version of the code.

I also tried out this code in my production.rb:

```
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

this is my development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true


  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations.
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = true

  config.action_mailer.preview_path = "app/spec/mailers/previews/user_mailer_preview.rb"

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://ancient-brushlands-24517.herokuapp.com/' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

end
```

and this is my build log

```
Overview Resources Deploy Metrics Activity Access Settings
Activity Feed  Build LogID 1d64e11a-7659-40ba-adf3-a5648a6785cc
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.1.4
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.0
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.1.4
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin bundle install -j4
       The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Resolving dependencies............
       Using rake 13.0.1
       Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.7
       Using minitest 5.14.2
       Using thread_safe 0.3.6
       Using zeitwerk 2.4.0
       Using builder 3.2.4
       Using erubi 1.9.0
       Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
       Using crass 1.0.6
       Using rack 2.2.3
       Using nio4r 2.5.4
       Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
       Using mimemagic 0.3.5
       Using mini_mime 1.0.2
       Using ast 2.4.1
       Using execjs 2.7.0
       Using aws-eventstream 1.1.0
       Installing aws-partitions 1.382.0
       Using jmespath 1.4.0
       Installing aws-sigv2 1.0.1
       Using msgpack 1.3.3
       Using rb-fsevent 0.10.4
       Using ffi 1.13.1
       Using will_paginate 3.1.7
       Using bundler 2.1.4
       Using diff-lcs 1.4.4
       Using dotenv 2.7.6
       Using method_source 0.9.2
       Using thor 1.0.1
       Using erubis 2.7.0
       Using temple 0.8.2
       Using tilt 2.0.10
       Using sexp_processor 4.15.1
       Using parallel 1.19.2
       Using pg 1.2.3
       Using rainbow 3.0.0
       Using regexp_parser 1.8.2
       Using rexml 3.2.4
       Using rspec-support 3.9.3
       Using ruby-progressbar 1.10.1
       Using unicode-display_width 1.7.0
       Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Using i18n 1.8.5
       Using nokogiri 1.10.10
       Using tzinfo 1.2.7
       Using puma 5.0.2
       Using rack-test 1.1.0
       Using websocket-driver 0.7.3
       Using marcel 0.3.3
       Using mail 2.7.1
       Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
       Using sprockets 3.7.2
       Using autoprefixer-rails 10.0.1.0
       Using aws-sigv4 1.2.2
       Using parser 2.7.2.0
       Using bootsnap 1.4.8
       Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
       Using bootstrap-will_paginate 1.0.0
       Using haml 5.2.0
       Using ruby_parser 3.15.0
       Using rspec-core 3.9.3
       Using rspec-expectations 3.9.2
       Using rspec-mocks 3.9.1
       Using turbolinks 5.2.1
       Using faker 2.14.0
       Using loofah 2.7.0
       Using activesupport 6.0.3.4
       Using rubocop-ast 0.8.0
       Using sass-listen 4.0.0
       Using html2haml 2.2.0
       Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
       Using globalid 0.4.2
       Using activemodel 6.0.3.4
       Using jbuilder 2.10.1
       Using sass 3.7.4
       Using rubocop 0.93.1
       Using actionview 6.0.3.4
       Using activejob 6.0.3.4
       Using activerecord 6.0.3.4
       Using rubocop-faker 0.2.0
       Using actionpack 6.0.3.4
       Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
       Using actioncable 6.0.3.4
       Using activestorage 6.0.3.4
       Using actionmailer 6.0.3.4
       Using railties 6.0.3.4
       Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
       Using actionmailbox 6.0.3.4
       Using actiontext 6.0.3.4
       Using dotenv-rails 2.7.6
       Using haml-rails 2.0.1
       Using jquery-rails 4.4.0
       Using rspec-rails 4.0.1
       Using sass-rails 5.1.0
       Using webpacker 4.3.0
       Using rails 6.0.3.4
       Installing aws-sdk-core 3.109.1
       Installing aws-sdk-accessanalyzer 1.13.0
       Installing aws-sdk-acm 1.38.0
       Installing aws-sdk-acmpca 1.30.0
       Installing aws-sdk-alexaforbusiness 1.43.0
       Installing aws-sdk-amplify 1.26.0
       Installing aws-sdk-apigateway 1.55.0
       Installing aws-sdk-apigatewaymanagementapi 1.19.0
       Installing aws-sdk-apigatewayv2 1.29.0
       Installing aws-sdk-appconfig 1.12.0
       Installing aws-sdk-appflow 1.2.0
       Installing aws-sdk-applicationautoscaling 1.48.0
       Installing aws-sdk-applicationdiscoveryservice 1.33.0
       Installing aws-sdk-applicationinsights 1.15.0
       Installing aws-sdk-appmesh 1.31.0
       Installing aws-sdk-appstream 1.48.0
       Installing aws-sdk-appsync 1.36.0
       Installing aws-sdk-athena 1.33.0
       Installing aws-sdk-augmentedairuntime 1.10.0
       Installing aws-sdk-autoscaling 1.47.0
       Installing aws-sdk-autoscalingplans 1.28.0
       Installing aws-sdk-backup 1.23.0
       Installing aws-sdk-batch 1.39.0
       Installing aws-sdk-braket 1.4.0
       Installing aws-sdk-budgets 1.36.0
       Installing aws-sdk-chime 1.37.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cloud9 1.29.0
       Installing aws-sdk-clouddirectory 1.29.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cloudformation 1.44.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cloudfront 1.43.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cloudhsm 1.27.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cloudhsmv2 1.30.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cloudsearch 1.26.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cloudsearchdomain 1.22.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cloudtrail 1.29.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cloudwatch 1.45.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cloudwatchevents 1.38.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cloudwatchlogs 1.38.0
       Installing aws-sdk-codeartifact 1.4.0
       Installing aws-sdk-codebuild 1.63.0
       Installing aws-sdk-codecommit 1.40.0
       Installing aws-sdk-codedeploy 1.37.0
       Installing aws-sdk-codeguruprofiler 1.12.0
       Installing aws-sdk-codegurureviewer 1.13.0
       Installing aws-sdk-codepipeline 1.37.0
       Installing aws-sdk-codestar 1.27.0
       Installing aws-sdk-codestarconnections 1.11.0
       Installing aws-sdk-codestarnotifications 1.8.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cognitoidentity 1.27.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider 1.47.0
       Installing aws-sdk-cognitosync 1.24.0
       Installing aws-sdk-comprehend 1.41.0
       Installing aws-sdk-comprehendmedical 1.23.0
       Installing aws-sdk-computeoptimizer 1.9.0
       Installing aws-sdk-configservice 1.53.0
       Installing aws-sdk-connect 1.34.0
       Installing aws-sdk-connectparticipant 1.8.0
       Installing aws-sdk-costandusagereportservice 1.28.0
       Installing aws-sdk-costexplorer 1.52.0
       Installing aws-sdk-databasemigrationservice 1.45.0
       Installing aws-sdk-dataexchange 1.10.0
       Installing aws-sdk-datapipeline 1.24.0
       Installing aws-sdk-datasync 1.27.0
       Installing aws-sdk-dax 1.27.0
       Installing aws-sdk-detective 1.11.0
       Installing aws-sdk-devicefarm 1.39.0
       Installing aws-sdk-directconnect 1.37.0
       Installing aws-sdk-directoryservice 1.34.0
       Installing aws-sdk-dlm 1.35.0
       Installing aws-sdk-docdb 1.25.0
       Installing aws-sdk-dynamodb 1.55.0
       Installing aws-sdk-dynamodbstreams 1.26.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ebs 1.11.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ec2 1.200.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ec2instanceconnect 1.11.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ecr 1.39.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ecs 1.70.0
       Installing aws-sdk-efs 1.36.0
       Installing aws-sdk-eks 1.45.0
       Installing aws-sdk-elasticache 1.44.0
       Installing aws-sdk-elasticbeanstalk 1.38.0
       Installing aws-sdk-elasticinference 1.10.0
       Installing aws-sdk-elasticloadbalancing 1.29.0
       Installing aws-sdk-elasticloadbalancingv2 1.53.0
       Installing aws-sdk-elasticsearchservice 1.43.0
       Installing aws-sdk-elastictranscoder 1.27.0
       Installing aws-sdk-emr 1.39.0
       Installing aws-sdk-eventbridge 1.16.0
       Installing aws-sdk-firehose 1.35.0
       Installing aws-sdk-fms 1.32.0
       Installing aws-sdk-forecastqueryservice 1.10.0
       Installing aws-sdk-forecastservice 1.11.0
       Installing aws-sdk-frauddetector 1.13.0
       Installing aws-sdk-fsx 1.31.0
       Installing aws-sdk-gamelift 1.38.0
       Installing aws-sdk-glacier 1.35.0
       Installing aws-sdk-globalaccelerator 1.23.0
       Installing aws-sdk-glue 1.75.0
       Installing aws-sdk-greengrass 1.37.0
       Installing aws-sdk-groundstation 1.15.0
       Installing aws-sdk-guardduty 1.42.0
       Installing aws-sdk-health 1.31.0
       Installing aws-sdk-honeycode 1.3.0
       Installing aws-sdk-iam 1.46.0
       Installing aws-sdk-identitystore 1.3.0
       Installing aws-sdk-imagebuilder 1.15.0
       Installing aws-sdk-importexport 1.24.0
       Installing aws-sdk-inspector 1.32.0
       Installing aws-sdk-iot 1.59.0
       Installing aws-sdk-iot1clickdevicesservice 1.26.0
       Installing aws-sdk-iot1clickprojects 1.26.0
       Installing aws-sdk-iotanalytics 1.34.0
       Installing aws-sdk-iotdataplane 1.26.0
       Installing aws-sdk-iotevents 1.20.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ioteventsdata 1.13.0
       Installing aws-sdk-iotjobsdataplane 1.25.0
       Installing aws-sdk-iotsecuretunneling 1.8.0
       Installing aws-sdk-iotsitewise 1.12.0
       Installing aws-sdk-iotthingsgraph 1.12.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ivs 1.5.0
       Installing aws-sdk-kafka 1.29.0
       Installing aws-sdk-kendra 1.14.0
       Installing aws-sdk-kinesis 1.30.0
       Installing aws-sdk-kinesisanalytics 1.29.0
       Installing aws-sdk-kinesisanalyticsv2 1.23.0
       Installing aws-sdk-kinesisvideo 1.30.0
       Installing aws-sdk-kinesisvideoarchivedmedia 1.29.0
       Installing aws-sdk-kinesisvideomedia 1.26.0
       Installing aws-sdk-kinesisvideosignalingchannels 1.8.0
       Installing aws-sdk-kms 1.39.0
       Installing aws-sdk-lakeformation 1.11.0
       Installing aws-sdk-lambda 1.51.0
       Installing aws-sdk-lambdapreview 1.24.0
       Installing aws-sdk-lex 1.32.0
       Installing aws-sdk-lexmodelbuildingservice 1.39.0
       Installing aws-sdk-licensemanager 1.20.0
       Installing aws-sdk-lightsail 1.39.0
       Installing aws-sdk-machinelearning 1.25.0
       Installing aws-sdk-macie 1.25.0
       Installing aws-sdk-macie2 1.13.0
       Installing aws-sdk-managedblockchain 1.17.0
       Installing aws-sdk-marketplacecatalog 1.9.0
       Installing aws-sdk-marketplacecommerceanalytics 1.29.0
       Installing aws-sdk-marketplaceentitlementservice 1.24.0
       Installing aws-sdk-marketplacemetering 1.31.0
       Installing aws-sdk-mediaconnect 1.28.0
       Installing aws-sdk-mediaconvert 1.58.0
       Installing aws-sdk-medialive 1.56.0
       Installing aws-sdk-mediapackage 1.36.0
       Installing aws-sdk-mediapackagevod 1.19.0
       Installing aws-sdk-mediastore 1.30.0
       Installing aws-sdk-mediastoredata 1.27.0
       Installing aws-sdk-mediatailor 1.32.0
       Installing aws-sdk-migrationhub 1.29.0
       Installing aws-sdk-migrationhubconfig 1.9.0
       Installing aws-sdk-mobile 1.24.0
       Installing aws-sdk-mq 1.33.0
       Installing aws-sdk-mturk 1.27.0
       Installing aws-sdk-neptune 1.30.0
       Installing aws-sdk-networkmanager 1.8.0
       Installing aws-sdk-opsworks 1.30.0
       Installing aws-sdk-opsworkscm 1.40.0
       Installing aws-sdk-organizations 1.52.0
       Installing aws-sdk-outposts 1.10.0
       Installing aws-sdk-personalize 1.19.0
       Installing aws-sdk-personalizeevents 1.14.0
       Installing aws-sdk-personalizeruntime 1.18.0
       Installing aws-sdk-pi 1.24.0
       Installing aws-sdk-pinpoint 1.47.0
       Installing aws-sdk-pinpointemail 1.24.0
       Installing aws-sdk-pinpointsmsvoice 1.21.0
       Installing aws-sdk-polly 1.37.0
       Installing aws-sdk-pricing 1.24.0
       Installing aws-sdk-qldb 1.11.0
       Installing aws-sdk-qldbsession 1.9.0
       Installing aws-sdk-quicksight 1.33.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ram 1.22.0
       Installing aws-sdk-rds 1.104.0
       Installing aws-sdk-rdsdataservice 1.23.0
       Installing aws-sdk-redshift 1.50.0
       Installing aws-sdk-redshiftdataapiservice 1.2.0
       Installing aws-sdk-rekognition 1.47.0
       Installing aws-sdk-resourcegroups 1.32.0
       Installing aws-sdk-resourcegroupstaggingapi 1.34.0
       Installing aws-sdk-robomaker 1.30.0
       Installing aws-sdk-route53 1.44.0
       Installing aws-sdk-route53domains 1.28.0
       Installing aws-sdk-route53resolver 1.21.0
       Installing aws-sdk-s3control 1.24.0
       Installing aws-sdk-s3outposts 1.0.0
       Installing aws-sdk-sagemaker 1.70.0
       Installing aws-sdk-sagemakerruntime 1.27.0
       Installing aws-sdk-savingsplans 1.12.0
       Installing aws-sdk-schemas 1.10.0
       Installing aws-sdk-secretsmanager 1.43.0
       Installing aws-sdk-securityhub 1.35.0
       Installing aws-sdk-serverlessapplicationrepository 1.32.0
       Installing aws-sdk-servicecatalog 1.50.0
       Installing aws-sdk-servicediscovery 1.31.0
       Installing aws-sdk-servicequotas 1.11.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ses 1.36.0
       Installing aws-sdk-sesv2 1.13.0
       Installing aws-sdk-shield 1.32.0
       Installing aws-sdk-signer 1.26.0
       Installing aws-sdk-simpledb 1.24.0
       Installing aws-sdk-sms 1.27.0
       Installing aws-sdk-snowball 1.35.0
       Installing aws-sdk-sns 1.33.0
       Installing aws-sdk-sqs 1.34.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ssm 1.94.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ssoadmin 1.3.0
       Installing aws-sdk-ssooidc 1.8.0
       Installing aws-sdk-states 1.36.0
       Installing aws-sdk-storagegateway 1.50.0
       Installing aws-sdk-support 1.28.0
       Installing aws-sdk-swf 1.25.0
       Installing aws-sdk-textract 1.21.0
       Installing aws-sdk-synthetics 1.9.0
       Installing aws-sdk-timestreamquery 1.1.0
       Installing aws-sdk-timestreamwrite 1.1.0
       Installing aws-sdk-transcribeservice 1.50.0
       Installing aws-sdk-transcribestreamingservice 1.22.0
       Installing aws-sdk-transfer 1.28.0
       Installing aws-sdk-translate 1.28.0
       Installing aws-sdk-waf 1.36.0
       Installing aws-sdk-wafregional 1.37.0
       Installing aws-sdk-wafv2 1.14.0
       Installing aws-sdk-workdocs 1.28.0
       Installing aws-sdk-worklink 1.21.0
       Installing aws-sdk-workmail 1.32.0
       Installing aws-sdk-workmailmessageflow 1.9.0
       Installing aws-sdk-workspaces 1.48.0
       Installing aws-sdk-xray 1.34.0
       Installing aws-sdk-s3 1.83.0
       Installing aws-sdk-resources 3.84.0
       Installing aws-sdk 3.0.1
       Updating files in vendor/cache
         * concurrent-ruby-1.1.7.gem
         * i18n-1.8.5.gem
         * minitest-5.14.2.gem
         * activesupport-6.0.3.4.gem
         * loofah-2.7.0.gem
         * actionview-6.0.3.4.gem
         * actionpack-6.0.3.4.gem
         * nio4r-2.5.4.gem
         * actioncable-6.0.3.4.gem
         * activejob-6.0.3.4.gem
         * activemodel-6.0.3.4.gem
         * activerecord-6.0.3.4.gem
         * activestorage-6.0.3.4.gem
         * actionmailbox-6.0.3.4.gem
         * actionmailer-6.0.3.4.gem
         * actiontext-6.0.3.4.gem
         * autoprefixer-rails-10.0.1.0.gem
         * bootsnap-1.4.8.gem
         * railties-6.0.3.4.gem
         * faker-2.14.0.gem
         * haml-5.2.0.gem
         * sexp_processor-4.15.1.gem
         * ruby_parser-3.15.0.gem
         * jbuilder-2.10.1.gem
         * parser-2.7.2.0.gem
         * puma-5.0.2.gem
         * sprockets-rails-3.2.2.gem
         * rails-6.0.3.4.gem
         * regexp_parser-1.8.2.gem
         * rspec-core-3.9.3.gem
         * rubocop-ast-0.8.0.gem
         * rubocop-0.93.1.gem
         * webpacker-4.3.0.gem
       Removing outdated .gem files from vendor/cache
         * actionview-6.0.3.2.gem
         * activejob-6.0.3.2.gem
         * minitest-5.14.1.gem
         * lumberjack-1.2.6.gem
         * puma-4.3.5.gem
         * haml-5.1.2.gem
         * nio4r-2.5.2.gem
         * i18n-1.8.4.gem
         * concurrent-ruby-1.1.6.gem
         * actionpack-6.0.3.2.gem
         * sexp_processor-4.15.0.gem
         * parser-2.7.1.4.gem
         * rspec-core-3.9.2.gem
         * actionmailbox-6.0.3.2.gem
         * webpacker-4.2.2.gem
         * activerecord-6.0.3.2.gem
         * spring-2.1.0.gem
         * rubocop-ast-0.2.0.gem
         * activestorage-6.0.3.2.gem
         * ruby_parser-3.14.2.gem
         * rails-6.0.3.2.gem
         * public_suffix-4.0.5.gem
         * autoprefixer-rails-9.8.5.gem
         * railties-6.0.3.2.gem
         * bootsnap-1.4.6.gem
         * loofah-2.6.0.gem
         * actioncable-6.0.3.2.gem
         * activesupport-6.0.3.2.gem
         * jbuilder-2.10.0.gem
         * rubocop-0.88.0.gem
         * actiontext-6.0.3.2.gem
         * faker-2.13.0.gem
         * regexp_parser-1.7.1.gem
         * actionmailer-6.0.3.2.gem
         * activemodel-6.0.3.2.gem
         * sprockets-rails-3.2.1.gem
       Bundle complete! 31 Gemfile dependencies, 333 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Removing aws-sdk (2.11.606)
       Removing aws-sdk-resources (2.11.606)
       Removing aws-sdk-core (2.11.606)
       Bundle completed (21.33s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
-----> Installing yarn-v1.22.4
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       ArgumentError: missing required option :name
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.83.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3/bucket.rb:874:in `extract_name'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.83.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3/bucket.rb:24:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.83.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3/customizations/bucket.rb:14:in `call'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.83.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3/customizations/bucket.rb:14:in `block in <class:Bucket>'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.83.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3/resource.rb:89:in `new'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.83.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3/resource.rb:89:in `bucket'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/config/initializers/aws.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `load'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `block in load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:665:in `load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:625:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `each'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_f52c4132_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

my aws.rb file:

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'eu-central-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
})

S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])
```

my environment.rb file:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Comment: The error message says: `config/initializers/aws.rb:6` ... `ArgumentError: missing required option :name`

Comment: What's in `config/initializers/aws.rb`?  I don't think any of the code you've shown above is relevant to the problem; the only prevalent issue is whatever's in that file.

Comment: @TomLord i added the 2 files and thank you so much for trying to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try not using `ENV['S3_BUCKET']` and instead replacing it with the
> actual string value that was stored in that environment variable. That
> fixed the issue for me.
>
> ```
> ENV['S3_BUCKET'] => whatever-this-value-really-is
> ```

Source: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1860

Comment: That's *sort of* a solution... the error came from [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/edd5bb1493540f6b7d8b4b9613cdf88c72f5e667/gems/aws-sdk-s3/lib/aws-sdk-s3/bucket.rb#L856). So why is your `ENV['S3_BUCKET']` not being set? Where were you expecting to set it? are you using it anywhere else, and expecting it to be set there, too? ....

Comment: ofcourse. in my .env file. it worked there before but seems like the version 3 of aws-sdk is not supporting this or something like that.

Comment: The `.env` file has got nothing to do with `aws-sdk`. Maybe you deleted it from production? Maybe you removed this variable from the file?

Comment: yes it has something to do with the aws-sdk, instead of hard coding your credentials and s3_Bucket(name of the bucket) into the source code, you can save those things in your .env files. But since aws-sdk v3 it still allows you to save your aws s3 bucket credentials in your .env files but doesnt want you to save the bucket name in there too.

Comment: I find it incredibly unlikely that upgrading `aws-sdk` from v2 to v3 will have meant that one of your variables stored in `.env` will have mysteriously stopped working. I think it's far more likely that you have changed *something else* which means the variable is undefined/not being loaded correctly.

Comment: There's no *need* to store a bucket name in an environment variable; it's no a security concern. But there's also no harm in doing it that way.